# Как правильно реализовать членов экземпляра наследника абстрактного класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, наследование

Есть абстрактный класс `Foo`

```py
from abc import ABC

class Foo(ABC):
    pass
```

Как сделать так, чтобы у экземпляров всех наследников этого класса был обязательно объявлен член `self.foo`?

[Находил решения](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2736255/10941639) реализации абстрактных `property` класса, но это не то, что нужно, так как нужно, чтобы этот член был доступен и для чтения, и для записи.

---

#### Зачем

Есть базовый класс `Descriptor`

```py
from abc import ABC

class Descriptor(ABC):
    pass
```

Дескриптор подразумевает, что у него должны быть какие-то поля (например, `self.fields = dict()`). К примеру, дескриптор файла:

```py
class FileDescriptor(Descriptor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fields = dict(
            name='name',
            path=PathDescriptor(),
            ...
        )
```

Далее этот дескриптор необходимо будет обогатить. Например,

```py
    def enrich(self, data):
        self.fields.update(data)
```

И так же должна быть возможность читать поля этого дескриптора

```py
file_desc = FileDescriptor()
file_desc.enrich(dict(name='new name'))
print(file_desc.fields['name'])
```

Необходимо, чтобы нельзя было инстанцировать наследников `Descriptor` (например, `FileDescriptor`) без объявленного в нём `self.fields`. Как это правильно реализовать?

---

Есть подозрения, что для этой задачи подойдут [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), но ни разу с ними не работал и пока не представляю, как это применить и применимо ли это вообще.

Comment: А зачем дескриптору быть именно абстрактным? Если подразумевается, что должны быть поля, то пусть он будеть просто базовым. И еще, зачем прятать все поля в словарь?

Comment: у вас опечатка. `def Foo(ABC):` замените на `class Foo(ABC):`

Comment: @mkkik Как в таком случае объявить этот член в базовом классе? Поля в словаре, т. к. есть методы, которые должны работать с дескрипторами независимо от их типа, для этого у них всех должен быть единый интерфейс.

Comment: @Danis Исправил, спасибо.

Comment: Реализовать в базовом классе сеттеры, геттеры для общих полей. В потомках добавлять необходимые поля (как поля экземпляра, а не элементы словаря). Но, возможно, я не очень понял вашу проблему.

Comment: @mkkik Не обязательно, что у каких-то двух дескрипторов будут общие поля. Есть, например, метод получения имён всех полей дескриптора. При таком подходе в каждом дескрипторе придётся реализовывать методы для получения всех полей (например, `return ['name', 'path', 'pid', ...]`), что является малым удовольствием :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для обновления содержимого словаря не обязательно, чтобы `property` было изменяемым

```
class C(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def fields(self):
        ...

class D(C):
    def __init__(self):
        self._fields = {}

    @property
    def fields(self):
        return self._fields
```

```
>>> x = D()
>>> x.fields
{}
>>> x.fields['key'] = 'value'
>>> x.fields.update({'key2': 'value2'})
>>> x.fields
{'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Ну а даже если нужно позволять менять не только содержимое, но и саму ссылку, `property` и так тоже умеет

```
class C(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def fields(self):
        ...

class D(C):
    def __init__(self):
        self._fields = {}

    @property
    def fields(self):
        return self._fields

    @fields.setter
    def fields(self, newfields):
        self._fields = newfields
```

```
>>> x = D()
>>> x.fields
{}
>>> x.fields = {'1': 2}
>>> x.fields
{'1': 2}
```

Comment: Т.е. в каждом наследнике надо будет объявлять собственный член-хранилище полей и реализацию геттера и сеттера этого хранилища? Наследников будет порядка 20-ти, Мне такое решение кажется слабо поддерживаемым.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Ну а для чего еще делать поле абстрактным, если не для того, чтобы за его реализацию полностью отвечали потомки. Можете наследоваться не напрямую базового класса, а от какой-то промежуточной реализации. Или приведите пример кода на другом языке, попробую адаптировать, потому, что задача не очень ясна.